# Display image group on button click using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How would I go about changing a group of images to their correct places based on the correct button that was pressed at the time.  I've found examples of a single button with multiple images, but cannot figure out how to use multiple buttons that place various images in a set location.

For example, I have three buttons that each are suppose to display three different images when they are clicked, taking the place of the whichever button was displayed earlier.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row center-block" style="margin:20px auto;">
        <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center">
            <button id="btnBasketball" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="basketballImg()">Basketball</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center">
            <button id="btnFootball" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="footballImg()">Football</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center">
            <button id="btnHockey" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="hockeyImg()">Hockey</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <center>
        <img id="img1" src="" class="img-rounded" alt="">
        <input type="button" onclick="pic1()"/>
    </center>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <center>
        <img id="img2" src="" class="img-rounded" alt="">
        <input type="button" onclick="pic2()"/>
    </center>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <center>
        <img id="img3" src="" class="img-rounded" alt="">
        <input type="button" onclick="pic3()"/>
    </center>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
function basketballImg(){
    picLocation1('img/bbImage1.png');
    picLocation2('img/bbImage2.png');
    picLocation3('img/bbImage3.png');
}

function footballImg(){
    picLocation1('img/fbImage1.png');
    picLocation2('img/fbImage2.png');
    picLocation3('img/fbImage3.png');
}

function hockeyImg(){
    picLocation1('img/hyImage1.png');
    picLocation2('img/hyImage2.png');
    picLocation3('img/hyImage3.png');
}
</script>
```

Is a script like this the best way to go about getting the group of images selected?  I'm open to any suggestions!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand right ,you are trying to change the images to a new set of images based on the button click then .
This is the simplest way I could think of though this is not the most efficient way but this should work

```
function basketballImg(){
document.getElementById('img1').href = 'img/bbImage1.png';
document.getElementById('img2').href = 'img/bbImage2.png';
document.getElementById('img3').href = 'img/bbImage3.png';

}

function footballImg(){
document.getElementById('img1').href = 'img/fbImage1.png';
document.getElementById('img2').href = 'img/fbImage2.png';
document.getElementById('img3').href = 'img/fbImage3.png';

}

function hockeyImg(){
document.getElementById('img1').href = 'img/hyImage1.png';
document.getElementById('img2').href = 'img/hyImage2.png';
document.getElementById('img3').href = 'img/hyImage3.png';

}
```

now on click of each button these set of images will be replaced by the ones that are there .

Comment: Heck yeah, that about worked!  The only thing I had to change was src instead of href.  Here's a follow up question, do you know how to make the images responsive??

Comment: Gud that it worked responsive, like fade in and fade out or some thing else pls elaborate ?